# Is the unit $f(x)=1$ an element of the algebra generated by a strictly monotone function?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

What I am tring to prove: the algebra generated by a strictly monotone function is dense in $C\lbrack 0,1\rbrack$.

What I have determined thus far: It seperates points but does it vanish? Consider the algebra generated by $x^2$. I can't determine whether the unit would be an element of this set of functions. If it is then there is a function such that $f(0) \neq 0$. Else it would vanish at 0.

An algebra does not necessarily contain a unit.

I am no algebraist and this is relating to the Stone Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: If you're working with Baby Rudin he defines an algebra as being closed under addition, multiplication and product by scalar, that is $f,g \in A$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ implies $f+g \in A, fg \in A,cf \in A$. So for an arbitrary algebra $A$, $f \equiv 1$ need not be in $A$. How are you defining "generated by"?

Comment: @Reveillark [Question C](https://books.google.com/books?id=jTBNAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA239&lpg=PA239&dq=limit+of+polynomials+in+h+of+strictly+monotone&source=bl&ots=cvbh638Cdt&sig=xdTjDqS7hzI6BolHvwzuM3yEyVA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LE4VVZHbK5XhoASvi4G4CA&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question linked in the comments asks, in particular, to show that, if $h$ is a strictly monotone function in $C[0,1]$, then every function $f\in C[0,1]$ is a limit of polynomials in $h$.

I think "polynomials in $h$" allows for the possibility of having constant functions (for example $1+h^2$). If you don't allow a nonzero constant term, then as you said, if you let $h=x^2$, then any polynomial $p(h)$ in $h$ with no constant term will take on the value of zero at 0, which means $|p(h)-1|_{\infty}\geq 1$, and you can't approximate the function $f=1$.

Comment: My professor assigns homework from the text but often changes the wording. The problem states "If $h$ is strictly monotonic then $Alg(h(x))$ is dense in $C\lbrack 0,1\rbrack$." I'm going to turn it in as a counterexample because as its worded, the theorem is false. Thanks for the explanation.